# Jetpack compose functions not showing/working properly

Tags: android, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WoXJ.png)in the android studio, I made the setup configuration of jetpack compose but jetpack functions are not showing up or missing import statements I have tried everything but jetpack compose is not working properly [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cLvn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1BvU.png) please help.

I have made the setup configuration of jetpack compose by following Google documentation but jetpack composes functions are not showing up / missing import statements.
I have copied the import statement of functions and it worked.

eg: I tried to use Column(), Row(), and Card() but not showing or is unrecognized mostly functions are like this.

Comment: Please share some code (also your build.gradle file)

Comment: please check the post images both included